# How to perform nested queries on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, kibana

I was trying to perform nested query on elastic-search that is, I have 2 queries in which the output of the first query must be used as an input in the second query, was going through the documentation of elastic-search but couldn't find any alternative.

The first query is:

```
    GET index1/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(imageName: xyz.jpg)"
        }
      }
    }
```

The output of this query would be of JSON format,

For example:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.2682955,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.2682955,
        "_source" : {
          "assetId" : "0",
          "descriptor" : "randomString",
          "bucketId" : [randomArray],
          "imageName" : "xyz.jpg"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The second query is:

```
GET index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace", 
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "bucketId": [randomArray that came as an output of the first query]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pqcode_score": {
        
             "descriptors": [
              {
            "descriptor": "randomString that came as an output of the first query"
              }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can we use the output of the first query inside the second query?

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: you will have to take the result of the first and use them in the second query, that is, you will have to run two queries.
It is not possible to do what you want in just one query.

Comment: Did you think of flattening your data to be able to search it in one go?
It is important to know Elasticsearch is not a relational database and usually supper slow when you try to run nested or parent child relationship queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Elasticsearch. You need to implement this at your application side.

You can call first query and get result then you can call the second query by passing the output of first query that is the only option.